# Laravel 5 how to clear cache using composer.json

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to clear view cache, and I need to clear view cache without composer.

Is possible to clear cache using composer.json `autoload`?

I have already tried the code below, but it was not working.

> routes.php

```
Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    return '<h1>View cache cleared</h1>';
});
```

Also, how should I use...

> **Cache::flush();**

...in my code controller.

Comment: "i need to clear view cache without composer.

is possible to clear cache using composer.json auto load."    So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Devon yes . please help me .

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not at all clear what you are asking because your statements are contradictory.

Comment: @Devon i have uploaded all modified files in server . but modified files not affected . how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Filemanager or a Simple PHP Code Delete the compiled views inside of `storage\framework\views`

Example:

```
Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
    $directory=storage_path('framework/views');  
    $files=File::allFiles($directory);
    File::delete($files);
    return '<h1>View cache cleared</h1>';
});
```

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5+, 
you can delete the compiled views in every run adding the code inside of function boot() in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.

Don't forget use File or \File in every call.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this?

```
public function index()
    {
        $value = Cache::flush();

        return view('your.view')->with($value);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not try clear browser cache ?

I think the view cache saved by browser.

Comment: in private browsing also same problem